# Make JSON data out of a Section from a text file

Tags: jquery, json, file

I am trying to create a JSON object out of a text file using this format:

```
[query]
query1 = SELECT * FROM TBL
query2 = SELECT * FROM VIEWS

[process]
process1 = exec tree
process2 = exec four
```

How can i make it be like this:

```
[
   {query :{
     query1 : select * from tbl,
     query2 : select * from views},
  {
    process : {process1 : exec tree, prcoess2: exec four 
  }
]
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "file.ini",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(r) {
            var $txt = r.split("\n") $.each($txt, function() {
                if (this.length > 0) {
                    if (this.match(/[[]]/g) != null) {}
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(r) {
            console.log(r.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: so what is your question? what is your issue?

Comment: Hi @Jacky how to make each section inside the [ ] to contain its succeeding items as its child objects?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what are you expect, but in case of validate that json: `[{
 "query": {
  "query1": "select * from tbl",
  "query2": "select * from views"
 },
 "process": {
  "process1": "exec tree",
  "prcoess2": "exec four"
 }
}]`
You can use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate

Comment: I dont need to validate the object as JSON, what we are trying to do here, is to convert the given items above (which is stored in a text file) and make it as a JSON object.

Comment: so you need to provide what language are you using to convert, what is blocking you when converting. Or if you want to convert manually, you can see my above comment

Comment: i'm using jquery 3 and here's my code
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url: "file.ini",
   dataType: "text",
   success: function(r){
    var $txt = r.split("\n")
    $.each($txt, function(){
     if(this.length > 0){
      if(this.match(/[\[\]]/g) != null ){

             }
     }
    });
 
   },
   error: function(r){
    console.log(r.responseText);
   }
  });

    });

Comment: that's what we need to help you :). i just edit your question to be more specific